# Linux distro on ARM64 Exynos 7870 Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1 sm-p580

Tags: ubuntu-for-android, arm64

I wanted to know if I can install a Linux arm distro like Ubuntu or Debian on my Android tablet and what guide I could follow to do this, it's a Galaxy Tab A 10.1 with s pen sm-p580, it has an Exynos Octa 7870 arm64 processor. I know that there are some versions compatible with arm64 but I would like to make sure that I am following the correct guide to avoid damaging the tablet since a page in the Debian website said that it was device specific.

I have seen some guides to install Linux with an app but I would prefer to replace Android with an experience that more similarly resembles a desktop environment, my device is already rooted.

Thank you.